# Need help writing a php script to generate a text file

Tags: php, batch-file, virtualbox

I am not a php expert at all.

I am working on a VOIP project and have to open a port range (10000 - 20000) in my virtual box.
The issue is that there is no such option to do it all in once. It has to be done one by one using a command line:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "Elastix 4.0" --natpf1 "guestssh,udp,,10001,,10001"
VBoxManage modifyvm "Elastix 4.0" --natpf1 "guestssh,udp,,10002,,10002"
VBoxManage modifyvm "Elastix 4.0" --natpf1 "guestssh,udp,,10003,,10003"
```

and so on till I reach

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "Elastix 4.0" --natpf1 "guestssh,udp,,20000,,20000"
```

Can anybody help me with a php script that will generate a TXT file which will contain

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "Elastix 4.0" --natpf1 "guestssh,udp,,10001,,10001"
to
VBoxManage modifyvm "Elastix 4.0" --natpf1 "guestssh,udp,,20000,,20000"
```

Thanks

Comment: We are happy to help you fix problems in your code, but this site is not designed to encourage others to write your code or development plan for you. Please make use of the available PHP documentation and follow a tutorial or three. Then, consider improving your question (or asking a new one) when you have a specific, code-related problem.

Comment: where is your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php
  $fp = fopen("outfile.txt", "w");
  for($x = 10000; $x<=20000; $x++){
      fprintf($fp , 'VBoxManage modifyvm "Elastix 4.0" --natpf1 "guestssh%d,udp,,%d,,%d"'."\n", $x - 9999, $x, $x);
  }
  fclose($fp);
```

Comment: That's the more memory efficient. Not that it should have any importance for the task at hand.

Comment: wroks great but just a small mistake.
guestssh has to be different for each line as well.
guestssh1, guestssh2, etc increment as well

Comment: updated in the answer ... suffix is $x - 9999

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow is made to help you with your questions, not to code for you.

Anyway,

```
$output = '';
for ($i = 10001; $i <= 20000; ++$i) {
    $output .= 'VBoxManage modifyvm "Elastix 4.0" --natpf1 "guestssh,udp,,' . $i . ',,' . $i . '"' . PHP_EOL;
}

$f = fopen('commands.txt', 'w');
fwrite($f, $output);
fclose($f);
```

Comment: I got it.
<?php
  $fp = fopen("C:\ifx\am\outfile2.txt", "w");
  for($x = 10000; $x<=20000; $x++){
      fprintf($fp , 'VBoxManage modifyvm "Elastix 4.0" --natpf1 "%d,udp,,%d,,%d"'."\n", $x, $x, $x);
  }
  fclose($fp);

?>

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution using [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) for printing the text you wrote to a file called "this_is_my_txt_file.txt".

```
file_put_contents('this_is_my_txt_file.txt', "VBoxManage modifyvm \"Elastix 4.0\" --natpf1 \"guestssh,udp,,10001,,10001\" to VBoxManage modifyvm \"Elastix 4.0\" --natpf1 \"guestssh,udp,,20000,,20000\"\n\r");
```

**Edit**
Oh, I see now that you've changed the question. Now, I'm afraid I can't understand it. You want it to look at each line and stop when reaching "guestssh,udp,,20000,,20000" and print that to the file?

Please elaborate on what you're trying to do.

Comment: exactly. Each line should have 
VBoxManage modifyvm "Elastix 4.0" --natpf1 "guestssh,udp,,10001,,10001"
VBoxManage modifyvm "Elastix 4.0" --natpf1 "guestssh,udp,,10002,,10002"
VBoxManage modifyvm "Elastix 4.0" --natpf1 "guestssh,udp,,10003,,10003"

Basically, an increment: 10001 +i until it will reach 20000

Comment: All right, then you'll have plenty of answers, I'll suggest @Sonar's answer for you, fwrite is just a wrapper for file_put_contents so you'll save a function call in the parsing :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = "";
for($i=1;$i<=10000;$i++){
$content.="VBoxManage modifyvm "Elastix 4.0" --natpf1 \"guestssh{$i},udp,,{$i+10000},,{$i+10000}\"\n";
}
file_put_contents('file.txt', $content);
```

Comment: works great but just a small mistake. guestssh has to be different for each line as well. guestssh1, guestssh2, etc increment as well.
VBoxManage modifyvm "Elastix 4.0" --natpf1 "guestssh1,udp,,10001,,10001"
VBoxManage modifyvm "Elastix 4.0" --natpf1 "guestssh2,udp,,10002,,10002"
VBoxManage modifyvm "Elastix 4.0" --natpf1 "guestssh3,udp,,10003,,10003"